# Memcached not working in PHP file but working on SSH - CentOS

Tags: cache, memcached, php-memcached

On my CentOS 7, Memcached is running and working on SSH but not working in the PHP file. I've followed this article: https://www.mynotepaper.com/install-memcached-on-centos-7. This method was working fine on my previous server.

I've tested Memcached using telnet. It works fine.

```sh
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
set test 0 100 5
Hello
STORED
get test
VALUE test 0 5
Hello
END
```

After storing data using telnet, I've tested on SSH via PHP command. It works too:

```sh
php -r '$c = new Memcached(); $c->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211); var_dump( $c->getAllKeys() );'
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

But in PHP file, it doesn't work. The PHP code:

```php
<?php
$c = new Memcached();
$c->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
var_dump( $c->getAllKeys() );
?>
```

It always shows `bool(false)`. Here's my [PHP info's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl2gk.png).

Could you please tell me what's my mistake?

Comment: How do you run the PHP script. Does it run from an Apache webserver with PHP module integrated? What does **getenforce** return?

Comment: Hi @user188737, I've tested on Apache & Nginx webserver with PHP module integrated. In my machine, SELinux is enabled. Do you think I'm facing the issue for SELinux? If so, could you please tell me the way to run Memcached in PHP file without disabling SELinux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a httpd integrated PHP module to do network access (even if it is to loopback network) in an enforcing SELinux environment, you have to do on your server (as root or with sudo):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Listing of booleans and info on Centos Wiki:
https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans